# SQL query to get consecutive years

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to write a SQL query that will pull how many consecutive years a user has had activities. If thay have not been active this year or the prior year then the result is 0. If they have been active in this year or the current year then I want how many consecutive years the user has had activities. Here are the tables . There userid is distinct in the Users table. The activities table can have many records for a userid and in a year.

| Users |
| --- |
| UserID |
| FirstName |
| LastName |

| UserActivities |
| --- |
| Userid |
| ActivityDate |
| ActivityType |
| ActivityDetails |

Sample 1 UserActivity data set.

| Userid | Date | A | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001357 | 02/12/2021 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/09/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/21/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 01/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 10/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/26/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/22/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/31/2018 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/19/2018 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/27/2018 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 03/15/2018 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/18/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/28/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/02/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/01/2016 | E | Engineering F |
| 001357 | 06/27/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/07/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |

The desired result for this would be 6 consecutive years of activities.

Sample 2 UserActivity data set.

| Userid | Date | A | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001357 | 02/12/2021 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/09/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/21/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 01/01/2020 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 10/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/26/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/22/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/18/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/28/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/02/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/01/2016 | E | Engineering F |
| 001357 | 06/27/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/07/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |

The desired result for this would be 3 consecutive years of activities.

Sample 3 UserActivity data set.

| Userid | Date | A | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001357 | 12/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 10/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/03/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/26/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/22/2019 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 12/18/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/28/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 02/02/2017 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 11/01/2016 | E | Engineering F |
| 001357 | 06/27/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |
| 001357 | 06/07/2016 | A | Alumni Giving |

The desired result for this data se would br 0 concecutive years of activities. This is because the user has to have been active in the current calendar year or the prior calendar year.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using? What have you tried to solve said problem? Why didn't it work?

Comment: MS SQL using sql to try and pull the information. Results have been that my count is off or there are missing users .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see a direct way of doing this with a simple query. But you could define a stored procedure for this. You could write a temp table for all of the years per id and then remove any that don't follow on up to the current year. Finally this could be used to join with the users table to get your desired result. EG:

```
-- get the current year
DECLARE @year INT = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE());

-- create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #tempYears (
    [UserId] INT,
    [Year] INT
);

-- populate the temp table with a distinct list of years for each person
INSERT INTO #tempYears
(
    [UserId],
    [Year]
)
SELECT DISTINCT [UserId], 
                [Year]
FROM (
    SELECT ua.[UserId],
           DATEPART(YEAR, ua.[ActivityDate]) AS [Year]
    FROM [UserActivities] ua
) allYears
WHERE allYears.[Year] <= @year
ORDER BY allYears.[Year] DESC;

-- continually delete any years where a following year is not found
DECLARE @loop BIT = 1;
WHILE @loop = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE ty FROM #tempYears AS ty
    WHERE ty.[Year] < @year
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempYears ty2 WHERE ty2.[UserId] = ty.[UserId] AND ty2.[Year] = ty.[Year] + 1);
    SET @loop = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempYears ty WHERE ty.[Year] < @year AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tempYears ty2 WHERE ty2.[UserId] = ty.[UserId] AND ty2.[Year] = ty.[Year] + 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END;

-- get the result
SELECT u.[UserId],
       u.[FirstName],
       u.[LastName],
       cy.[Years]
FROM (
    SELECT ty.[UserId],
           COUNT(ty.[Year]) AS [Years]
    FROM #tempYears ty
    GROUP BY ty.[UserId]
) cy
INNER JOIN [Users] u
  ON u.[UserId] = cy.[UserId]

-- drop the temp table
DROP TABLE #tempYears
```

Comment: That seems to work but I am only getting consecutive years for 549 users and there are 79,000 distinct users.

Comment: I assume that the remaining users do not have an activity for the current year so are not included. If you want this to show 0 years for those users change the final join on the users table to a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: There are 7923 people that have an activity this year or in 2020 so at a minimum the result would need to capture them.